# Index and match give an error

Tags: microsoft-excel, modeling

I want my Excel sheet to work as a model. And I want to find the value which is on the 'crossing point' of G37 and G38, which are respectively 12 and 6. 
The following function worked out for several model, but now it does not work out for the model I am building at the moment. Whatever I try, it gives #N/B.

`=INDEX(L36:BU96;MATCH(G38;K36:K96;0);MATCH(G37;L35:BU35;0))`

Does anyone see what might give the error?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you have several options.

1) IF YOU WANT TO KEEP USING THE FORMULA: The formula you included worked for me when I replaced the semicolons with commas. Give that a shot?

2) ALTERNATIVE 1- SIMPLIFY WITH INDEX ONLY. If your inputs really are 12 and 6, you could simplify what you're doing by using these as arguments in your INDEX formula. For example, this variant of your formula worked for me to also deliver the intersection (what you call the "crossing point") of the two inputs you describe: =INDEX($K$35:$W$47,7,13)

3) ALTERNATIVE 2 - USE NAMED RANGES AND INTERSECT OPERATOR. You could select your whole index range (headers included) and select Formulas->Create from Selection to create a set of named ranges and then use the intersect operator to find the intersection between the two ranges as in this video: https://youtu.be/wWkgJ-nSQBU?t=149.

Do any of those work for your needs?